# How to create a list of date time and check if it matches with current date time, then print current datetime?

Tags: python, date, datetime

```
import datetime,  time

now= time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print 'Current time is:',
print now

date_lit=[]
date_list=['2015-10-17 15:10:00', '2015-10-17 15:10:01', '2015-10-17 15:10:02','2015-10-17 15:10:03']
date_list = (datetime.datetime.strptime(t, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") for t in date_list)
currentTimeMachine = datetime.datetime.now()

print (date_list)



for date in date_list1:
 if date in date_list1[now]:
print date
```

I am a beginner with python and so i would like to know how i should create the list that contains some date time and then i will create a for loop to check if the current date time matches with the date time in the list. If it does, then i should print out the current date time. This is the code i wrote so far. Please help!

Comment: You do realise that the current time is more likely to be NOT in your list?

Comment: print date_list gives me <generator object <genexpr> at 0x02D81FD0> and please explain more about where are you facing the problem

Comment: i don't understand how should fix that. @ Mohit Chandak

Comment: because he used a generator comprehension not list comprehension. what he wants to do is on the commented for loop below in his example.

Comment: @Nick change the line `date_list = (datetime.date...` to use the square bracket `[` like `date_list = [datetime.date...` and a closing bracket as well `]`

Comment: Now how should i create the for loop to check date time in list matches with the current time or not?

Answer (score 0):

You should realise that the current time is moving forward and its likely that it will not be in your list unless your list have future times on each second.

That said, you dont have to create a list of datetime object. You can compare the strings directly.

```
import datetime, time

now= time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print 'Current time is:',
print now

date_list = ['2015-10-17 15:10:00', '2015-10-17 15:10:01', '2015-10-17 15:10:02','2015-10-17 15:10:03']

print(date_list)

if now in date_list:
    print now
else:
    print '%s is not in date_list' % now
```

Comment: Thanks. Also i would like to know Is it possible to create a .txt file and store the list in that and then create a for loop to iterate through all the date time and check if it is there and if so then print out? @dopstar